# Facebook API - Check Likes and Comments of Post

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to check the number of likes and comments that a particular post has? I wanna display that number on my site so i need to reference the API somehow to get that result. I am looking for either a PHP or a javascript solution. This will also be done dynamically. I want to keep track of likes posted by my app to different users so I'm thinking i should store the post id when I make the post. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each post in facebook has a specific Id

You can use graph api to grab this id and see all the comments, likes and shares of it.

You simply have to make a POST call and grab the produced JSON

More information can be found on the links below
http://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_10150189643478553

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=19292868552_10150189643478553

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: Cool so i can pretty much grab that then add the likes and the comments to get my desired result?

Comment: Exactly! You can make a jquery ajax call and afterwards loop the JSON object to get your desired data